# Express authentication - cannot send headers after sent

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a function that restricts route access by verifying that a stored session user/pass matches what is in the database

```
var checkAuth = function(req, res, next){
  if(typeof(req.session.user) === 'undefined') {
    req.session.user = { name: '', pass: '', loggedIn: false }
  }
  $R.user.validateLogin(req.session.user, function(err){
    if(err) res.redirect('/login')
    else {
      req.session.user.loggedIn = true
      next()
    }
  })
}

app.get('/restricted', checkAuth, function(req, response){
  response.render('index')
})
```

It seems to work fine as it will redirect to the /login page if a person is not athenticated, but immediately after redirecting the app shuts down with the error

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I have traced the error down to the res.redirect('/login') but can't figure out how to remedy my error.

**EDIT: My login route handler**

```
app.get('/login', function(req, response){
  $R.page.addStyles(['forms','user/user'])
  response.render('user/login')
})
app.post('/login', function(req, response){
  $R.user.validateLogin(req.body, function(err, res){
    if(err) response.end(JSON.stringify({error: err.message}))
    else {
      req.session.user = req.body
      response.end(JSON.stringify({ok: true}))
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you've shown, but in the handler for the route "/login"

Comment: It would seem that in $R.page.addStyles you are writing something to the response. This would cause the error when you tried to response.render('user/login'). if you res.write(), .end(), .send() or .json() before you .render(), that would be what you're looking for.

Comment: I only get the error after the redirect from checkAuth() addStyles only adds filepaths to a module array to include on the layout and works fine if I enter /login in the url. The error is the res.redirect(/login) according to the stack output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the function:

```
$R.user.validateLogin(req.session.user, function(err){
```

is aysnchronous. The `checkAuth` function should return a true/false immediately, or redirect. The current flow of your login is like this:

1. app.get('/restricted') fires
2. checkAuth fires
3. $R.user.validateLogin fires (**asynchronously**)
4. At this point, checkAuth returns control to app.get('/restricted')
5. response.render('index') executes
6. Code inside of $R.user.validateLogin executes, calling the redirect.

The problem is you don't control whether 5 or 6 executes first. Ultimately, both will execute because you aren't stopping #5 from happening.

To fix this, your checkAuth function needs to return and/or redirect without using a callback inside (or executing a callback synchronously). Since you are already validating user logins in your 'login' route, you should be able to check the user session and return or do the redirect synchronously, like this:

```
var checkAuth = function(req, res, next){
  if(typeof(req.session.user) === 'undefined') {
    req.session.user = { name: '', pass: '', loggedIn: false }
  }

  if (!req.session.user.loggedIn) {
    // req.session.user.loggedIn = true should be set in the 'login' route, in $R.user.validateLogin
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    // if we already have a req.session.user and they are logged in, keep going
    next();
  }
}
```

Apologies for any syntax errors, I didn't test the above code.

Comment: I assumed since the presence of next() callback indicated that the route middleware was asynchronous also, only continuing once next() was called. Your solution worked, thanx!