# Mongoose findById possibly sending Express headers?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to send an error if a condition is true using the Mongoose function findById. The problem is that Mongoose appears to be setting the res Express object and is then throwing an error when I try to set the headers myself. Here is the code:

```
console.log(res.headersSent); // false

Trade.findById(req.body.trade, function (err, trade) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Ensure user is not making an offer on their own item

    Item.findById(trade.listing, function (err, item) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (req.decodedId == item.user) {

            console.log(res.headersSent); // true (?)

            return res.status(403).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'You cannot make an offer on your own item'
            })
        } else {
            return;
        }
    })
```

And here is the stack trace for the error:

```
    false // res.headersSent() before calling Trade.findById()
    POST /api/v2/offer 200 148.799 ms - 162
    true // res.headersSent() after calling Item.findById() and checking error condition
    _http_outgoing.js:335
        throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
              ^
    Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/Users/Matt/Dropbox/work/TradeRate/prototype/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/Users/Matt/Dropbox/work/TradeRate/prototype/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:154:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/Users/Matt/Dropbox/work/TradeRate/prototype/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:240:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/Users/Matt/Dropbox/work/TradeRate/prototype/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:142:21)
at /Users/Matt/Dropbox/work/TradeRate/prototype/server/controllers/offers.js:48:40  // LINE THAT CONTAINS return res.status(403).send ...
at /Users/Matt/Dropbox/work/TradeRate/prototype/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1169:16
at /Users/Matt/Dropbox/work/TradeRate/prototype/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:103:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
18 Jul 15:26:39 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What could be causing this error? Is there aspect of the Mongoose API that sets the response headers that I'm missing?

---

EDIT: I added my full (updated) exported route handler in case that has some context that would make the problem more clear.

```
   // POST /api/offer

exports.createOffer = function (req, res, next) {
console.log(res.headersSent);

Trade.findById(req.body.trade, function (err, trade) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
    } // not good to throw from async events, let express' error handling middleware take care of it

    // Ensure user is not making an offer on their own item

    Item.findById(trade.listing, function (err, item) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }

        if (req.decodedId == item.user) {

            console.log(res.headersSent); // true (?)

            res.status(403).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'You cannot make an offer on your own item'
            });

        }
        // all done with async stuff, pass the request long
        next();
    });

    // If trade is expired, reject the offer

    if (trade.expiresOn < Date.now()) {
        res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'This trade has expired and cannot accept new offers'
        });
    }

    // Create new offer and add data

    var newOffer = new Offer();

    newOffer.items = req.body.items;
    newOffer.trade = req.body.trade;

    newOffer.save(function (err, offer) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    // Add offer to items in offer

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.items.length; i++) {
        Item.findById(req.body.items[i], function (err, item) {
            if (err) throw err;

            item.offers.push(newOffer._id);

            item.save(function (err, item) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    }

    // Add offer to trade

    trade.offers.push(newOffer._id);

    trade.save(function (err, trade) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    return res.send(newOffer);
});
```

};

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293780/express-authentication-cannot-send-headers-after-sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely new answer, disregard my old one it was all wrong (it's been a while since I've used express).

Anyway the problem is you're calling async functions which return immediately so at the bottom there when you're calling `return res.send(newOffer);`, you're doing it before any of those callbacks return. So you returned before you

- Check if the user is trying to create an offer on their own item
- Add the new offer id to the items
- Save any of those changes

Another problem is your loop there will likely fail horribly. There's no guarantee that you'll be pushing those items in order because `findById` and `save` as async, they return instantly and may be executed in any order. Plus there's no reason at all to save after every push. You need to either wait for each `findById` to return before continuing the loop (so you can't use a basic for loop, most likely a callback) or more correctly, just use a mongoose update query to do this all at once (you don't need to load an item to push an offer to it, just use `$push`)

The best way to handle all of this in express is with middleware. So change your code to this (I've added a dependency on [http-errors](https://github.com/jshttp/http-errors) to make error handling easier.

I'm assuming you're using the most recent version of express:

### The Offer Route

```
var httpError = require('http-error') // needed for ezpz http errors
var express = require('express'); // needed for express.Router()


// middleware that loads the trade
function loadTrade(req, res, next) {
  Trade.findById(req.body.trade, function (err, trade) {
    req.trade = trade;
    next(err, trade);
  })
}

// middlware that checks expiration
function checkExpired(req, res, next) {
  if(req.trade.expiresOn < Date.now())
    next(httpError(403, 'This trade has expired and cannot accept new offers'));
  else next();
}

// middleware makes sure the user isn't making an offer on their own item
function checkIsOwner(req, res, next) {
  Trade.findById(req.trade.listing)
       .select('user')
       .exec(function(err, listing) {
          if (err) next(err)
          else if (listing.user == req.decodedId) next(httpError(403, 'You can not make an offer on your own item'))
          else next();
        })
}

// now we can create an offer
function createOffer(req, res, next) {
  // req.trade was loaded and validated by our middleware
  // if next(err) was called at any point this function wouldn't be called
  var trade = req.trade;
  Offer.create({trade: trade._id, items: req.body.items}, function (err, offer) {
    if (err) {
      next(err); // we only call next to trigger the error handler
      return;
    }
    // now push the new offer id to all the items
    Item.update({$in: req.body.items}, {$push: offer._id}, function (err, offer) {
      if (err) next(err)
      else res.json(newOffer);
    })
  });
}


exports.createOffer = express.Router()
  .post(loadTrade)
  .post(checkExpired)
  .post(checkIsOwner)
  .post(createOffer);
```

For handling errors I'd add this after you've setup all the routes (where you have your `app.post('/api/v2/offer', ....)` stuff:

```
app.use('/api/v2/*', function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
});
```

Now whenever you call `next(err)`, this error handler will be called and send a status code and error message.

Comment: Sorry but I am unfamiliar, what would my express handler look like?

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work, I updated my question with the full exported function - please let me know if there's anything you'd like to see that'd make figuring this out easier. Thanks!

Comment: Splitting the route into separate functions solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Just to be clear though this just happens to be the cleanest way to do it in express, you can put it all in one function but you'd need to nest all your callbacks so everything happens in the correct order